# How to get current url in handlebars

Tags: node.js, url, handlebars.js, geturl, getcurrenturl

i have a function getQuantityValueFromURL in helpers

```
getQuantityValueFromURL: (url) => {
    const currentURL = new URL(url);
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(currentURL.search);
    return urlParams.get('quantity');
}
```

how can i pass the current url of the site when calling this function

```
{{getQuantityValueFromURL current url}}
```

i tried using window.location.href for the url but it didn't work

Comment: What is `current` and what is `url` in the `{{getQuantityValueFromURL current url}}` snippet?